# Can I get Oracle to favor particular indexes?

Tags: oracle, performance

Oracle 11.2 R2 RAC

I have a database which has many dynamic and ad hoc queries run again it.  The stats are all up to date, but often because of large numbers of complex joins and heavy parameterization, the CBO picks a less than optimal plan.

There are a couple of tables that are extremely common and if they exist in the query, its almost always a win to force a particular index rather than a full table scan (which is what it tries to pick most often).

Is there a way to artificially get the CBO to favor particular indexes without having to hint individual queries? Not a hint on the queries, but a way to make the index itself look cheaper or such?

Comment: It may be a better idea to refactor the offending SQL, so that a single SQL_ID will be called on each work flow (using binds to serve the parameterization). This will allow you to baseline individual IDs or force RBO on them, which you say you want to avoid. 

You may also consider creating indexes on the columns that these queries leverage, such that it's "too good" for CBO to not pick it.

Comment: Can't possibly refactor, its thousands of different ones that are generated from stored user input parameters that they can change at any moment.

Comment: I'm speaking to refactoring the code to take in bind variables, which would dynamically bind to the stored user input parameters. This would create a "single" SQL_ID that serves a workflow, despite thousands of potential and dynamic inputs.

Comment: No, the joins and what columns in the where clause are dynamically created based on criteria that the users select.  Things like the actual values are already bind variables, but there's still thousands of variations.

Comment: I doubt your statement. Usually (let's say in 99% of all cases) Oracle optimizer will take the best, i.e. fasted execution plan. The cases where optimizer does not pick the best plan are exceptional. I remember an Oracle optimizer training where the teacher told: It is getting harder and harder to find examples where Oracle does not automatically select the best plan and give us the possibility to further optimize.

Comment: Wow, so...you're saying when I add a hint and it goes from 10 minutes to 10 seconds, I'm just imagining that ?  You're absolutely right that it does the right thing 99% of the time, but its that 1 percent that I'm chasing.  If I've got 100k distinct sql_ids, and its getting 99% right, i'm still chasing 1000 plan issues...

Answer (score 4):

The cost of an index depends on its clustering factor.

Clustering factor measures how well aligned are the rows in the table - in respect of the columns of the index in question. It is calculated as: inspect all the rows from table in order (order is defined by the index columns). Every time a row is found to be in a different (not the currently inspected) block, increase the clustering factor by 1. If consecutive values in a table are near each other in the same block, the clustering factor of the index will be low. If consecutive values are scattered across the table, the clustering factor will be high.

Simply put, the lower the clustering factor is, the cheaper the index becomes.

Despite the myth, the clustering factor can not be decreased by rebuilding the index, because it depends on the table data distribution. However, you can set the clustering factor manually by:

```
begin
  dbms_stats.set_index_stats
  (
   ownname       => 'USER1', 
   indname       => 'INDEX1',
   clstfct       => 1234,
   no_invalidate => false
  );
end;
/
```

Where 1234 is the desired clustering factor. The lowest valid value of the clustering factor is the number of the table blocks. The highest valid value of the clustering factor is the number of the table rows. But this does not mean you can not set it lower or higher.

This setting will be lost on the next index statistics collection.

You can use the above to change other statistics as well that have effect on the cost: `blevel` (`indlevel`) or `leaf_blocks` (`numlblks`).

Comment: This definitely sounds closer to what I'm looking for.  I'll give it a shot and come back.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **[optimizer_mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams167.htm)** to `first_rows` or `first_rows_{n}`

Take in consideration that this change may have negative impact on use-cases that are more suitable for a full scan.

Comment: Thats a bit more of the nuclear option - thats all indexes, not just the ones I care about.

Comment: Why don't you want to hint the specific queries?

Comment: Thousands of dynamically generated queries .

Comment: And can't you add the same hint for all of them?

Comment: Not really, some of them don't do a full table scan naturally.  Ideally, they'd stay the same. I admit, its a quirky problem.

Comment: Also, first_rows doesn't produce my desired effect

Comment: What do you mean?